# Error: A "url" property or function must be specified, except url is specified

Tags: backbone.js, view, models

I have a Conversation model and a view that displays this model. This model is fetched from the server without any problem (the url property works fine then), and the view is rendered.
However, when I attempt to destroy the model in a function of the view, I get the error 'A "url" property or function must be specified', even though when I display said url right before the destroy call, it is exactly the url it should be.

Here is the code for the model:

```
MessageManager.models.Conversation = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        uid: '',
        title: '',
        messages: [],
        users: [],
        dateUpdated: null,
        isNew: true,
        message: ''
    },
    url: function(){
        var url = '/api/conversations';
        if(this.get('uid').length > 0) url += '/'+this.get('uid');
        return url;
    }
});
```

And the view:

```
MessageManager.views.ConversationFull = Marionette.CompositeView.extend({
    template: this.template(MessageManager.templates.ConversationFull),
    childView: MessageManager.views.MessageListItem,
    childViewContainer: '#message-container',
    events: {
        'click a#btn-delete-conversation': 'deleteConversation'
    },
    deleteConversation: function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var self = this;
        console.log(self.model.url()); //This returns a correct url

        self.model.destroy({//This fires the error
            error: function(model, result, xhr){
                console.log(result.responseText);
            },
            success: function(model, response, options){
                MessageManager.conversations.sync();
                AMMain.router.pNavigate('welcome/');
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Can anyone give some insight on how to resolve this problem? Is there something wrong in the way I declare the model?

EDIT: It should be noted that other calls (like fetch or sync) on this model fire the same error, even though the original fetch works without a problem.

EDIT2: Well, not completely out of the frying pan yet, but I changed the way I defined the model's url, using urlRoot and the "id" attribute, and now the DELETE request is sent to the server without error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

defsq answer is good. The only thing missing is to define the `idAttribute` on your model, since it's not the convention-based `id` field, but `uid`.

```
MessageManager.models.Conversation = Backbone.Model.extend({
    idAttribute: 'uid',
    defaults: {
        uid: '',
        title: '',
        messages: [],
        users: [],
        dateUpdated: null,
        isNew: true,
        message: ''
    },
    urlRoot: "/api/conversations"
});
```

You don't need to append the "id" manually. Just tell Backbone that your id attribute is `uid` and everything else will work. In fact, you can event call `mymodel.id` to get the id of the model -event if it's stored internally as `uid`. :)

http://backbonejs.org/#Model-idAttribute

Personally I don't like all that default values. Everything will be `undefined` if you don't set default values, which you can simply guard against with an if (undefined is a `falsey` value).

```
if(!model.get("messages")){
   //no messages
}
```

Comment: I was searching for how idAttribute was used! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Then mark as answered for future users to find out. glad to help! ;)

Answer (score 1):

It happens because you have to specify `urlRoot` property of the model. Without it `url` is not considered. So try this maybe:

```
MessageManager.models.Conversation = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        uid: '',
        title: '',
        messages: [],
        users: [],
        dateUpdated: null,
        isNew: true,
        message: ''
    },
    urlRoot: function() {
        var url = '/api/conversations';
        if (this.get('uid').length > 0) url += '/'+this.get('uid');
        return url;
    }
});
```

Documentation [says](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-urlRoot):

> urlRootmodel.urlRoot or model.urlRoot() 
>   Specify a urlRoot if you're using a model outside of a collection, to enable the default url function to generate URLs based on the model id. "[urlRoot]/id"
>   Normally, you won't need to define this. Note that urlRoot may also be a function.

And source code for `Backbone.Model` url method:

```
url: function() {
  var base =
    _.result(this, 'urlRoot') ||
    _.result(this.collection, 'url') ||
    urlError();
  if (this.isNew()) return base;
  return base.replace(/([^\/])$/, '$1/') + encodeURIComponent(this.id);
},
```

Comment: I added the urlRoot attribute, and I don't have an error anymore. However, instead of calling the DELETE method on the server, the "destroy" function goes directly to success, with an undefined response. It seems something still goes wrong internally, how could I go about figuring out what?
Also the success call does not execute the rest of the calls (like the sync and the navigate), which is extremely odd, considering a console.log call still manages to happen. It's as though backbone became completely numb after this call.