# Backbone - Unable to fetch data from Specified URL

Tags: backbone.js

I'm getting the following error even though I'm pretty sure I have specified the URL in my collection:
[image]

```
Uncaught Error: A `url property or function must be specified
```

Here's my collection:

```
import $ from 'jquery';
import Backbone from 'backbone';
import ViewModel from './view-model';
import InstancesCollection from '../instances/instances-collection-model';

export default Backbone.Collection.extend({

    model: ViewModel,

    url: $.createURL('/api/view'),

    initialize: (models = []) => {
        models.forEach(element => {
            element.instances = new InstancesCollection(element.instances);
        });
    },

    parse: (response) => {
        return response.views;
    }
});
```

I tried to follow the response given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26400751/4756519) but in vain. Does anybody know if I'm missing something here?

Just in case you needed to see the model as well, here it is:

```
    import _ from 'lodash';
import Backbone from 'backbone';
import InstancesCollection from '../instances/instances-collection-model';

export default Backbone.Model.extend({

    defaults: {
        id: null,
        name: null,
        count: 0,
        instances: []
    },

    initialize: function (models) {
        const attributes = Object.assign({}, this.defaults, models);

        if (_.isArray(attributes.instances)) {
            this.set({instances: new InstancesCollection(attributes.instances)}, {silent: true});
        }
    },

    toJSON: function () {
        let json = Object.assign({}, this.attributes);
        for (const attr of Object.keys(json)) {
            if ((json[attr] instanceof Backbone.Model) || (json[attr] instanceof Backbone.Collection)) {
                json[attr] = json[attr].toJSON();
            }
        }
        return json;
    }
});
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Does `$.createURL('/api/view')` return a string? could you try removing your custom code and see what happens?

Comment: Thank you for your time and reply. Yes, it returns this string: `../api/view`. May I ask which specific custom code you would like me to remove?

Comment: The custom `initialize` and `parseJSON`... Imagine if you have to replicate this in a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.com) without the rest of application... you'll probably isolate the problem while doing so...

Comment: I removed them and the error stayed the same. Really at loss here, but I'll keep on digging. Thank you anyway for you time.

Comment: Strange... it should just append model `id`/`clientId` to collection URL... Are you using backbone 1.33? When you are sending the request can you check if the model has an `id` attribute and it's valid? (not `null`/`undefined` etc)

Comment: Tried: `url: function() { return $.createURL('/api/view'); }` ..?